# Assign value to multiple variables in dotnet webapi object with mongodb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, webapi

I have this simple Object class, which is filled by json content of the api controller.

```
[BsonId] public string Id { get; }
[JsonIgnore] public string UserId { get; set; }
```

I want both of these variables to access the same GUID.

1. Making guid static does not work as I want to create a new one on every object creation
2. I tried using a constructor, but it seems not to be supported

   ```
    UserObject()
    {
    string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Id = guid;
    UserId = guid;
    }
   ```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You should always specify what you observe, not just state "It seems not supported" Then people tend to ignore the question. Since UserId is ignored by deserialization it will be assigned a new guid each time. Id on the other hand will be initialized by its setter hence preserve its value. Skip the constructor and simply do
[BsonId] public string Id { get; }= Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
[JsonIgnore] public string UserId => Id;

Comment: why do you need two duplicate fields?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly why do you need two duplicate fields?

anyway...

change object to:

```
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

Mongo will store it as string but you can use GUID in code

when you create object just use:

```
   new objectname(){
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need both fields, you could "redirect" the `UserId` property to read and write the value of `Id`, e.g.:

```
[BsonId] public string Id { get; }
[JsonIgnore] public string UserId 
{ 
  get { return Id; }
  set { Id = value; }
}
```

When the JSON is deserialized in the controller, the `Id` property is set; as the `UserId` property uses the value of the `Id` property internally, the value of the properties is the same.